# I want my image to have the same width as height in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am making a design to use it in a LazyColum, it is a simple design but there is something I don't get, this is my code:

```kotlin
Card(
                    colors = CardDefaults.cardColors(containerColor = LightGray),
                    shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)
                        .padding(horizontal = 10.dp, vertical = 5.dp)
                ) {
                    Row(modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .height(IntrinsicSize.Min)) {
                        AsyncImage(
                            model = monument.image,
                            contentDescription = stringResource(
                                id = R.string.home_monument_content_description
                            ),
                            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .width(100.dp)
                                .fillMaxHeight()
                                .padding(10.dp)
                                .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
                        )
                        Column(Modifier.padding(10.dp)) {
                            Text(
                                text = monument.name,
                                fontSize = 18.sp,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.SemiBold
                            )
                            Text(
                                text = monument.description,
                                fontSize = 14.sp,
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 10.dp),
                                overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                                maxLines = 2,
                                lineHeight = 20.sp
                            )
                            Text(
                                text = monument.author,
                                fontSize = 12.sp,
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 10.dp),
                                color = Color.LightGray,
                            )
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I think I am misusing the intrinsic sizes as I don't understand them very well. I would like my AsyncImage to grow to as tall as it can but keep the same height and width proportions. That is, if I add more fields in my column, I want the image size to expand to whatever the column has been growing to.

So far I have managed to make it grow in height, but I can't keep the same width so that the image looks square and not rectangular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the modifier with Aspect Ratio 1F. This will make it square.

```
  AsyncImage(
        model = monument.image,
        contentDescription = stringResource(
            id = R.string.home_monument_content_description
        ),
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxHeight()
            .aspectRatio(1f)  // This ensures a square aspect ratio
            .padding(10.dp)
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
    )
```

Remember that this approach may lead to the image being cropped more than desired on one axis because of the ContentScale.Crop content scale you're using. If you want the whole image to be visible and don't mind it being potentially smaller than the maximum size allowed by the row, consider using ContentScale.Fit instead.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make it square all the time, you need to get rid of hard coded `width` Modifier and set `aspectRatio` to `1F` so it will make sure it matches with new height

```
modifier = Modifier
   .fillMaxHeight()
   .aspectRatio(1F)
   .padding(10.dp)
   .clip(RoundedCornerShape(10.dp))
```